# JSP c:out instruction is not processed

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I am using JSP 2.1 in a Java EE web application.

My JSP page is something like this:

```
<html><body>
<% String myText = (String) request.getAttribute("myText"); %>
<h1><c:out value="${myText}"/></h1>
</body></html>
```

if myText="h & b", then the generated html page is:

```
<html><body>
<h1><c:out value="h & b"/></h1>
</body></html>
```

so, the c:out instructions has not been processed.

Replacing the first line by:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
```

does not help; still the same problem.

If I add the following line at the top of the jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

or  this one:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

I get the following error:
*No tag library could be found with this URI. Possible causes could be that the URI is incorrect, or that there were errors during parsing of the .tld file.*

What is the problem?

ps: and what documentation should I read about this?
I am reading the JSP 2.1 spec, but I don't find the answer.
http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jsp-2.1-fr-eval-spec-oth-JSpec/jsp-2_1-fr-spec.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a JSTL implementtion in your class path. You can for example download [an implementation from Apache](http://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/standard/).

Comment: And yes, the taglib declaration line must be there. The correct one is `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`

Comment: great, adding the <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> and jstl dependency to pom.xml works correctly <dependency>
 <groupId>jstl</groupId>
 <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
 <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>